# AWS CloudFront now requiring alternate cname to have security certificate causing problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

- I have an elastic beanstalk instance at **jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com**
- I have a **jthinkws.com** dns setup with *Route 53*
- I have **direct.jthinkws.com** pointing to CNAME **jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com**
- I then have Cloudfront distribution with *Origin Domain Name* set to  **direct.jthinkws.com**  and *alternate cname* set to **search.jthinkws.com**
- I have **search.jthinkws.com** record in **Route 53** set to A, Alias point to the cloudfront distribution.
- My application then accesses via search.jthinkws.com so if it is a new request then Cloudfront will make a request from **jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com** and cache the result, if the request is already cached by Cloudfront then no  need to go to **jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com**

**This has worked very well for many years.**

Recently I had to recreate my Cloudfront distribution. So firstly I temporarily point **search.jthinkws.com** to **jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com** domain then disable and delete old distribution and then create new Cloudfront distribution. But it is no longer working because it will not allow me to add **search.jthinkws.com** as an alternate cname because it has no security certificate

> com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException:
> To add an alternate domain name (CNAME) to a CloudFront distribution,
> you must attach a trusted certificate that validates your
> authorization to use the domain name. For more details, see:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements

So I went to AWS Certifcate Manager to get a certificate but it says if I use DNS Validation then AWS will create CNAME records that cannot be modified, I am concerned this will break my configuration. Whois doen't list any email addresses (although they are visible within the company that I pay for the domain name) so Im not confident that will work either.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have it working.

If you **validate with DNS** the record it creates is not for the domain but a subdomain such as

```
 _72d863ce40127aac000cf4d20fe972ea.search.jthinkws.com
```

rather than

```
 search.jthinkws.com
```

so it doesn't affect configuration, also if AWS is the DNS Manager for these domains then it can create the *Route53* records for you.

A couple of problems I had:

- When I first create certificate it created I am by default region *EU-West Ireland* but its turns out they have to be created in *US East Virginia* for Cloudfront to be able to use them.
- You have to enter the **arn** of  the certificate into Cloudfront, there is no dropdown so you have to got to Certificate Manager, view the certificate and copy and paste the **ARN** field

e.g

arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:623196878787496:certificate/d049878781-20b6-4cb5-a70a-6e86758936d2